# Why odata parameters are not working in office graph to get Planner Taks?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get my tasks on Planner using **beta/tasks** but I am having trouble trying to add filters, I have tried the following structure:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/tasks?$filter=percentComplete eq 100
```

OR

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/tasks?$filter=assignedTo eq 'me' and percentComplete eq 100
```

but the results are always the task assigned to me, ignoring the part about the percent completed and bringing me all.

I would like your help to get the right request or to know if this filter is not supported.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tasks APIs does not yet support filtering.  It's a bug that this does not throw an error but rather silently ignores your filter request.

Comment: I was hoping that was not the case, but I get it's beta version. Any ideas on when can we expect a solution?